# express and Hihttp2 not working for me

Tags: node.js, express, nodes

I am testing HTTP 2 with express and it is not working for me.
I have downloaded a simple sample and when looking in the chrome dev tool's ->network->protocol I see http/1.1 not 2

node v0.10.33
express 4.13.3

Code sample:

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, http2!')
})


var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync("blablabla.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("blablabla.crt")
};

require('http2').createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

express does not support `http2` module.

In express 5.x it will be supported.